# How to group by array?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have got dataset below:

```
id | object |
------------|
id1| object1|
id1| object2|
id1| object3|
id2| object1|
id2| object3|
id2| object4|
id3| object2|
id3| object3|
id3| object4|
id4| object1|
id4| object2|
id4| object3|
id5| object1| 
id5| object2|
id6| object1|
id6| object2|
```

I need to group by array of duplicate data using column 'object' like this:

```
object | count()
----------------
object1|   2   |<-from id1 and id4
object2|   2   |
object3|   2   |
----------------
object1|   2   |<-from id5 and id6
object2|   2   |
----------------
object1|   1   |<-from id2
object3|   1   |
object4|   1   |
----------------
object2|   1   |<-from id3
object3|   1   | 
object4|   1   |
```

How can I group my data by coincidental arrays?

Comment: How do you decide which IDs you want to bucket together?  If it's really coincidental, you'll have to build a case statement to put the ones you want together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to identify groups of IDs based on their set of common objects.  In your first group IDs 1 and 4 are associated with the same three objects 1, 2, and 3.

To do this the first step is to uniquely identify each group.  In postgresql, the array_agg analytic (window) function can be used to do this.  Once the groups are identified, then you can count the relevant IDs as shown below and in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/568f9/30):

**Query 1**:

```
with grp as (
  select id
       , object
       , array_agg(object) 
         over (partition by id order by object
               rows between unbounded preceding
                        and unbounded following) objs
   from YourData
)
select min(id) first_id
     , object
     , count(id) cnt
  from grp
 group by objs, object
order by cnt desc, first_id, object
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/568f9/30/0)**:

```
| first_id |  object | cnt |
|----------|---------|-----|
|      id1 | object1 |   2 |
|      id1 | object2 |   2 |
|      id1 | object3 |   2 |
|      id5 | object1 |   2 |
|      id5 | object2 |   2 |
|      id2 | object1 |   1 |
|      id2 | object3 |   1 |
|      id2 | object4 |   1 |
|      id3 | object2 |   1 |
|      id3 | object3 |   1 |
|      id3 | object4 |   1 |
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want something like this:

```
select objects, array_agg(id) as ids, count(*) as num_ids
from (select id, array_agg(object order by id) as objects
      from t
      group by id
     ) i
group by objects;
```